# Is it possible to sort by the duration of time when its computed based on the joined table?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, subquery

I have a query to get the total number of duration of when the user become internal,hm,rec status. I wanted to ask, is it possible to sort it by total number of duration when it's re calculated from another table? Please see my query structure to understand further.

The user can be assigned into many status. It can be that he was in internal status for 4th times,rc for 2 times and etc.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE creation_date < NOW()";
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$res = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
  $res[] = $row;
  $res['duration'] = getTimeDuration($row['userId'],$row['startDate']);

}

function getTimeDuration($userId,$startDate);
{
    $sql = "SELECT statusDate FROM userStatus WHERE userId=$userId AND status IN('internal','hm','rec') ORDER BY statusDate DESC
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    While($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
    {
         $diff = $row['statusDate']-$startDate;
         $duration = $duration + $diff;
    }

     return $duration;
}
```

This is the table structure
user Table

```
+----------+--------------+
| userId   | startDate    | 
+----------+--------------+
| 1         | 2011-09-18   |
+----------+--------------+
| 2         | 2012-05-25   |
+----------+--------------+
```

userStatus Table

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| userId   | statusDate   | status       |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2012-09-18  |  internal    |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2012-10-18  |  hm          |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2012-10-25  |  rec         |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2012-11-05  |  manager     |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2012-11-15  | assistant    |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2012-12-05  | internal     |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 2         | 2012-10-05  | rec          |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 2         | 2012-11-05  | internal     |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Output:
http://screencast.com/t/BsgouWSc5H3m

In my screenshot, USER ID: 1 had a total time duration all in all for 1589. USER ID: 2 has a duration of 297. What I want is to add the ability to sort base on the total time of duration. In this case, if DESC USER ID 1 will show first. Then, if ASC USER ID: 2 will show first.

Comment: Please edit your question with the results you want.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Updated now.

Comment: In your screenshot you calculate duration with startdate, isn't the total time duration the differnce between startdate and last statusDate?

Comment: It's doesn't matter if its the last statusDate, there's a possibility also that it will not be the last statusDate. As long as, the status value is 'internal','hm','rec'. User status can be change from time to time.

Comment: Anyone has an idea on this?